# Multiple Leaflet maps

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, leaflet

I have this webpage that I am developing which involves multiple Leaflet maps on the webpage using jQuery from top to bottom. [See this lo-fi wireframe for a closer look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Ju2.jpg) . I have tried to add multiple `<div>`s in index.html and multiple map variables in main.js (and yes, styled in CSS), as well as
[creating a function like kboul's answer here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53596185/16538252) but no matter what I do, it ends up just being one map that does not load the base map. For now, I have included the code that works with only one map [See this image of what the code looks like with all the layers on and working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PTuC.jpg) Also please note the coordinates have been redacted because there were so many.

Here is my code:

```js
/*Stylesheet by Will P. Campbell,2021*/

//map to contain '31500' polygon
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([45.5, -89.5], 7);

//map to contain '27500' polygon
var map2 = L.map('mapid2').setView([45.5, -89.5], 7);

//map to contain '24000' polygon
var map3 = L.map('mapid3').setView([45.5, -89.5], 7);

//map to contain '20500' polygon
var map4 = L.map('mapid4').setView([45.5, -89.5], 7);

//map to contain '17000' polygon
var map5 = L.map('mapid5').setView([45.5, -89.5], 7);

//map to contain '14600' polygon
var map6 = L.map('mapid6').setView([45.5, -89.5], 7);

//map to contain '11000' polygon
var map7 = L.map('mapid7').setView([45.5, -89.5], 7);


var baseMap = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain-background/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
  attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  subdomains: 'abcd',
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: 18,
  ext: 'png'
}).addTo(map);


/*Glacier 11000*/
var Toe_11000 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          //redacted
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID_1": 1,
      "OBJECTID": 1,
      "Years_Ago": 11000,
      "SHAPE_Leng": 387749.141631,
      "Shape_Le_1": 5.06435076694,
      "Shape_Area": 0.429078160361,
      "filename": "11000.jpg"
    }
  }]
};

var g11000 = L.geoJSON(Toe_11000, {
  style: {
    color: "#e41a1c"
  }
});

g11000.on({
  click: function() {
    $("#panel").html(Toe_11000.features[0].properties.Years_Ago + " Years Ago" + info11000 + glacierInfo + selfPlug);
  }
});

/*Glacier 14600*/
var Toe_14600 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [-90.65116417499996, 47.70293454200004],
          [-90.72482365299999, 47.673924999000064],
          [-90.79822703099995, 47.63344243800003],
          [-90.87151684099996, 47.592913355000064],
          [-90.93607653299995, 47.54240954900007],
          [-90.98389479799994, 47.50486972300007],
          [-91.01266156999998, 47.46605101600005],
          [-91.03524057399994, 47.43585163000006],
          [-91.09569047499997, 47.40672034700003],
          [-91.16068607799997, 47.39608128700007],
          [-91.20242634199997, 47.38136616700007],
          [-91.24370674999994, 47.34807033200008],
          [-91.24727017899994, 47.32089010200008],
          [-91.27829107399998, 47.30054916700004],
          [-91.35252049299999, 47.24684182500005],
          [-91.42454322999998, 47.19454164700005],
          [-91.49851758599999, 47.142169952000074],
          [-91.58297018999997, 47.09531966900005],
          [-91.69593298799998, 47.02941600500003],
          [-91.78970295499994, 46.95941544900006],
          [-91.82835428899995, 46.930232197000066],
          [-91.91162510599997, 46.86744039100006],
          [-91.99554737199998, 46.82743409100004],
          [-92.06911560299994, 46.79183942000003],
          [-92.12271105199994, 46.779428163000034],
          [-92.18228311199994, 46.76116312500005],
          [-92.25397574199997, 46.73548525600006],
          [-92.32346255299996, 46.70837829200008],
          [-92.37452539699996, 46.68875637000008],
          [-92.41380912499994, 46.68507654200005],
          [-92.47155654999995, 46.67669948400004],
          [-92.49779041299996, 46.66041357700004],
          [-92.53630909799995, 46.640992280000034],
          [-92.60352557599998, 46.61519304900003],
          [-92.65025475699997, 46.595545755000046],
          [-92.66997578199994, 46.57508444400003],
          [-92.69410222099998, 46.56023089900003],
          [-92.73425967299994, 46.53498854400004],
          [-92.79268852199999, 46.503571829000066],
          [-92.84256524699998, 46.468051606000074],
          [-92.88183268599994, 46.42849094400003],
          [-92.92753540999996, 46.394466917000045],
          [-92.94989701799994, 46.34959887800005],
          [-92.95186608799997, 46.30954130100008],
          [-92.92975250899997, 46.28153421700006],
          [-92.85925850399997, 46.27331860700008],
          [-92.79127616799997, 46.27357100900008],
          [-92.71321257399995, 46.27830917600005],
          [-92.63952461199995, 46.28860811000004],
          [-92.57829646799996, 46.301436514000045],
          [-92.50925582199994, 46.32440533500005],
          [-92.44221727099995, 46.347289440000054],
          [-92.41261793199999, 46.37792243000007],
          [-92.37035638299994, 46.40309578500006],
          [-92.32010085699994, 46.43555965100006],
          [-92.22421472899998, 46.46604055800003],
          [-92.16676037899998, 46.47714513900007],
          [-92.07164040799995, 46.47747958900004],
          [-91.96355058399996, 46.462242262000075],
          [-91.88129117799997, 46.47505522800003],
          [-91.84860834599993, 46.487018110000065],
          [-91.75759648199994, 46.48702458100007],
          [-91.67480884399998, 46.485409692000076],
          [-91.61092690599997, 46.49347106100004],
          [-91.53298945499995, 46.517401738000046],
          [-91.46184380399995, 46.56548027200006],
          [-91.39439978099995, 46.60108704600003],
          [-91.31293960199997, 46.66110276500007],
          [-91.18166198599994, 46.731109263000064],
          [-91.12163612599994, 46.77552488500004],
          [-91.02482937399998, 46.78786178000007],
          [-90.98063779999995, 46.797773128000074],
          [-90.96927097899999, 46.782631328000036],
          [-90.95760682899999, 46.75034730400006],
          [-91.00666688699994, 46.706114670000034],
          [-91.04472870499995, 46.66958103600007],
          [-91.09664029099997, 46.636712301000045],
          [-91.13687825499994, 46.57726777900007],
          [-91.18839689999999, 46.532931133000034],
          [-91.22591702999995, 46.48300696300004],
          [-91.22480609399997, 46.433490293000034],
          [-91.18738430599996, 46.359591409000075],
          [-91.12616009499999, 46.325921202000075],
          [-90.99618142799994, 46.285217860000046],
          [-90.89141040599998, 46.26322281700004],
          [-90.77320977799997, 46.256463342000075],
          [-90.59165834999999, 46.22897204100008],
          [-90.47359851299996, 46.22571206300006],
          [-90.21011180299996, 46.22840493600006],
          [-90.07834092799999, 46.21714115300006],
          [-89.99052527699996, 46.20002253800004],
          [-89.63663278999996, 46.19754044900003],
          [-89.30472963899996, 46.19409865700004],
          [-89.14564109599996, 46.193020372000035],
          [-89.10690236799996, 46.21367948200003],
          [-88.97509624199995, 46.21828879600008],
          [-88.74396655199996, 46.24455812300005],
          [-88.43920812199997, 46.263282384000036],
          [-88.18463496799995, 46.27857294900008],
          [-88.00977466999996, 46.175646776000065],
          [-87.99389010599998, 46.04677587200007],
          [-88.03142757799998, 45.90454467200004],
          [-88.07824403599994, 45.733876871000064],
          [-88.11693049199994, 45.64521481500003],
          [-88.15630836499997, 45.53154329200004],
          [-88.25459067099996, 45.31159869500004],
          [-88.32963412999999, 45.169820886000025],
          [-88.40834291299996, 45.06376788400007],
          [-88.48581727299995, 44.99336901300006],
          [-88.79481685399998, 44.90415892300007],
          [-88.88639060299994, 44.84792515000004],
          [-88.88261184299995, 44.78357859500005],
          [-88.94319230899998, 44.76271860500003],
          [-88.97231671099996, 44.62840776200005],
          [-89.00318747399996, 44.57866096200007],
          [-89.02004076199995, 44.46804576400007],
          [-89.04649611099995, 44.37537170000007],
          [-89.10740785599995, 44.30082986600007],
          [-89.08883401599996, 44.21492877800006],
          [-89.02088686299999, 44.117891385000064],
          [-88.83475711099999, 43.998228366000035],
          [-88.68786675299998, 43.92517043600003],
          [-88.62533997199995, 43.84939582800007],
          [-88.57299960499995, 43.76656712400006],
          [-88.46045322499998, 43.73294585800005],
          [-88.39507582999994, 43.78207346700003],
          [-88.33422715399996, 43.841949181000075],
          [-88.26389529699998, 43.883781630000044],
          [-88.26171217099994, 43.95878690500007],
          [-88.25436012199998, 44.04085874400005],
          [-88.13665456199999, 44.003267237000045],
          [-88.04759712699996, 44.00177966800004],
          [-87.97724235799996, 44.03271403600007],
          [-87.91264601899996, 44.03869804900006],
          [-87.85100620199995, 43.96251794800003],
          [-87.84031258699997, 43.84797273600003],
          [-87.77934997599993, 43.76104507100007],
          [-87.69970123099995, 43.65226923900008],
          [-87.59451333699997, 43.57506238600007],
          [-87.41895871099996, 43.54264457600004],
          [-87.19847646199997, 43.53030423300004],
          [-87.05535483399996, 43.54457143500008],
          [-86.90199607799997, 43.56552812900003],
          [-86.73246550099998, 43.61082922300005],
          [-86.59688342599998, 43.66046715300007],
          [-86.47311237099996, 43.75675903800004],
          [-86.41494068499998, 43.905016706000026],
          [-86.38487126299998, 43.99339418100004],
          [-86.33611529199999, 44.14190469500005],
          [-86.23094835399996, 44.23494796600005],
          [-86.07578505799995, 44.32618325100003],
          [-85.99546925899995, 44.409139733000075],
          [-85.93780993299998, 44.44997420000004],
          [-85.94529025199995, 44.48596854700003],
          [-85.88575853799995, 44.551719080000055],
          [-85.82903334099996, 44.64612264200008],
          [-85.67299230199995, 44.65817042300006],
          [-85.49721378799995, 44.66565292100006],
          [-85.37988257999996, 44.69311130300008],
          [-85.26070073999995, 44.74180747400004],
          [-85.20102381099997, 44.79647274300004],
          [-85.12731019099994, 44.896951657000045],
          [-85.07522771199996, 44.976883351000026],
          [-84.82164997499996, 47.579520486000035],
          [-90.67336377599997, 47.71242423500007],
          [-90.65116417499996, 47.70293454200004]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID_1": 1,
      "OBJECTID": 1,
      "Years_Ago": 14600,
      "SHAPE_Leng": 2202706.20984,
      "Shape_Le_1": 25.0028099606,
      "Shape_Area": 17.1995913109,
      "filename": "14600.jpg"
    }
  }]
}

var g14600 = L.geoJSON(Toe_14600, {
  style: {
    color: "blue"
  }
});

g14600.on({
  click: function() {
    $("#panel").html(Toe_14600.features[0].properties.Years_Ago + " Years Ago" + info14600 + glacierInfo + selfPlug);
  }
});

/*Glacier 17000*/
var Toe_17000 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          //redacted
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID_1": 1,
      "OBJECTID": 2,
      "Years_Ago": 17000,
      "SHAPE_Leng": 2261336.18634,
      "Shape_Le_1": 24.4337768448,
      "Shape_Area": 21.6098467975,
      "filename": "17000.jpg"
    }
  }]
}

var g17000 = L.geoJSON(Toe_17000, {
  style: {
    color: "#4daf4a"
  }
});

g17000.on({
  click: function() {
    $("#panel").html(Toe_17000.features[0].properties.Years_Ago + " Years Ago" + info17000 + glacierInfo + selfPlug);
  }
});

/*Glacier 20500*/
var Toe_20500 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            //redacted
          ]
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID_1": 1,
      "OBJECTID": 1,
      "Years_Ago": 20500,
      "SHAPE_Leng": 3087165.91023,
      "Shape_Le_1": 33.5221258781,
      "Shape_Area": 32.9568211425,
      "filename": "20500.jpg"
    }
  }]
}

var g20500 = L.geoJSON(Toe_20500, {
  style: {
    color: "#ffff33"
  }
});

g20500.on({
  click: function() {
    $("#panel").html(Toe_20500.features[0].properties.Years_Ago + " Years Ago" + info20500 + glacierInfo + selfPlug);
  }
});

/*Glacier 24000*/
var Toe_24000 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          //redacted
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID_1": 1,
      "OBJECTID": 1,
      "Years_Ago": 24000,
      "SHAPE_Leng": 3034250.36063,
      "Shape_Le_1": 33.0014683974,
      "Shape_Area": 35.7394984299,
      "filename": "24000.jpg"
    }
  }]
}

var g24000 = L.geoJSON(Toe_24000, {
    style: {
      color: "#984ea3"
    }
  }

);

g24000.on({
  click: function() {
    $("#panel").html(Toe_24000.features[0].properties.Years_Ago + " Years Ago" + info24000 + glacierInfo + selfPlug);
  }
});

/*Glacier 27500*/
var Toe_27500 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          //redacted
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID_1": 1,
      "OBJECTID": 1,
      "Years_Ago": 27500,
      "SHAPE_Leng": 2984589.95454,
      "Shape_Le_1": 32.3931138132,
      "Shape_Area": 34.4347324387,
      "filename": "27500.jpg"
    }
  }]
}

var g27500 = L.geoJSON(Toe_27500, {
    style: {
      color: "#ff7f00"
    }
  }

);

g27500.on({
  click: function() {
    $("#panel").html(Toe_27500.features[0].properties.Years_Ago + " Years Ago" + info27500 + glacierInfo + selfPlug);
  }
});

/*Glacier 31500*/
var Toe_31500 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          //redacted
        ]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "OBJECTID_1": 1,
      "OBJECTID": 2,
      "Years_Ago": 31500,
      "SHAPE_Leng": 1478866.18087,
      "Shape_Le_1": 15.9994195189,
      "Shape_Area": 9.83976333148,
      "filename": "31500.jpg"
    }
  }]
}

var g31500 = L.geoJSON(Toe_31500, {
  style: {
    color: "#a65628"
  }
});

g31500.on({
  click: function() {

    $("#panel").html(Toe_31500.features[0].properties.Years_Ago + " Years Ago" + info31500 + glacierInfo + selfPlug)
  }
});

var overlayMaps = {
  "31500 years ago": g31500,
  "27500 years ago": g27500,
  "24000 years ago": g24000,
  "20500 years ago": g20500,
  "17000 years ago": g17000,
  "14600 years ago": g14600,
  "11000 years ago": g11000

};

var glacierLayers = L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

```css
/*Stylesheet by Will P. Campbell,2021*/

body {
  background-color: #ECECEC;
}

#mapid,
#mapid2,
#mapid3,
#mapid4,
#mapid5,
#mapid6,
#mapid7 {
  position: fixed;
  height: 650px;
  width: 60%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#panel {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  border: 5px outset black;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>WISCONSIN GLACIER TIME LAPSE</title>

  <!--put your external stylesheet links here-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet/leaflet.css">
  <!--[if IE<9]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.ie.css">
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

  <h1>WISCONSIN GLACIER TIME LAPSE</h1>

  <!-- map 1 -->
  <div id="mapid"></div>
  <!-- map 2 -->
  <div id="mapid2"></div>
  <!-- map 3 -->
  <div id="mapid3"></div>
  <!-- map 4 -->
  <div id="mapid4"></div>
  <!-- map 5 -->
  <div id="mapid5"></div>
  <!-- map 6 -->
  <div id="mapid6"></div>
  <!-- map 7 -->
  <div id="mapid7"></div>

  <div id="panel"><b>Glacier Information Panel</b><br>
    <p>Use the checkbox and click on each glacier to learn more about them!</p>
  </div>

  <!--put your initial page content here-->

  <!--you can also use this space for internal scripts or stylesheets;
        place these within <script> or <style> tags-->

  <!--put your external script links here-->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/geojson.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Please let me know if you need any more clarification. I'm new to StackOverflow as well so I apologize if this is an improper or repeat question.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a question, what are all those `info31500` ? Is that somehow related to the map?

Comment: Also, in your code, you have only one `var map = L.map('mapid').setView([45.5, -89.5], 7);` what are the other?

Comment: You have an error in the markup of `glacierInfo` You start the markup with `<p><a>` but you're ending it like `</p></a>` which is incorrect.

Comment: Why you say you need multiple maps in your page, but in your CSS you use `position: fixed` for one only?

Comment: Those variables at the top are strings that describe each of the polygons of glaciers I made in a panel to the right. They pop up as a string in the panel when you click on an active polygon. Secondly, I don't have any other maps written for now but for the others, I plan on them being clones of the first one, just with an individual polygon on each map.

Comment: Would you like me to edit it so there are more maps?

Comment: Could you add the leaflet script  (<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>) and also try and add some layers so we can see what exactly the issue is?

You are referencing local JS files, but they don't work here.

Comment: Yes, I could add a few of the polygons back in and add the link in there if thats what you mean

Comment: I will also add in the other map frames I plan to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an Object `mapsData` with properties that match your DIV Element `data-map` value.

Loop your Elements DIVs `ELS_map.forEach(initMap);` and apply the data you stored beforehand for each map *ID* inside the `mapsData`

```js
const L_tiles = 'https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain-background/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}';
const L_options = {
  attribution: 'Tiles: <a href="http://stamen.com">SD</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>  &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OSM</a> contrib.',
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: 18,
  ext: 'png'
};

// ALL YOUR DATA GOES HERE!
// Name your properties the same as data-map="" value in HTML
const mapsData = {
  glacier_1: {
    center: [45.5, -89.5],
    zoom: 7,
    description: "Glacier one Lorem...",
    // add title, shapes etc here
  },
  glacier_2: {
    center: [45.5, -89.5],
    zoom: 7,
    description: "Glacier 2 Ipsum...",
    // add title, shapes etc here
  },
};

const initMap = (EL) => {
  const id = EL.dataset.map; // rerturns i.e: "glacier_1"
  const data = mapsData[id];
  const map = L.map(EL).setView(data.center, data.zoom);
  L.tileLayer(L_tiles, L_options).addTo(map);
};

const ELS_map = document.querySelectorAll("[data-map]");
ELS_map.forEach(initMap);
```

```css
[data-map] {
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />

<div data-map="glacier_1"></div>
<div data-map="glacier_2"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Roko, Ill try this out and see how it works!

Comment: @wpc6707 sure, the code is quite straightforward, but let me know if you'll have issues to add data to the `mapsData` object and represent them on each map! (PS, you have a hint in the `initMap` function: see how I used `data.center`, `data.zoom` etc)

Comment: So just to be clear, underneath the "description:" property lines, I would then add the shape, colors and event listeners for each shape?

Comment: ok so I used your suggestion and managed to get my map frames to show up, but not the maps themselves. I ended up having to remove the variable key word from the front of my variables so there would be no errors but I think that broke my map. Also, where should I be putting `overlayMaps` and `glacierLayers` for my event listeners which are at the end of main.js?

Comment: @wpc6707 create a new property in a desired `mapsData` glacier inner Object, i.e: `g: {}` where `{}`  is all the data you need (or call it somewhat better than just *g*) - than inside `initMap` use it similarily as `L.tileLayer(L_tiles, L_options).addTo(map);` which means something like: `L.control.layers(null, data.g).addTo(map);`  I told you, you have all the hints you need ;) Again, expand the `mapsData`! if it makes more sense to you to call the main properties like: `glacier_17000` instead of `glacier_1`. Just remember to than also change the data-map=" attributes accordingly

Comment: See the `// add title, shapes etc here` ? that's where you need to create your new properties and their data.

Comment: Ok I got that to work. If I have checkbox layer control, is there a way I could have each layer show on each map individually? For example, 31500 on map 1, 27500 on map 2...

Comment: @wpc6707 I'm not sure how to test those layers, but I believe the same way. Whatever is *custom* (specific map) - goes inside the specific `mapsData`. Not sure what checkboxes are you talking about... Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236189/discussion-between-wpc6707-and-roko-c-buljan).