# How to create the multiple leaflet maps on the page in angular

Tags: angular, leaflet, openstreetmap, react-leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have created the leaflet open street map given below.

**.component.ts**

```
 map = L.map('map').setView([12.876, 80.599], 12);  

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
```

I have Placed the map in html page as given below

**.component.html**

```
<div class ="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-7">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And mentioned the height in css as

**.component.css**

```
#map{
  height: 650px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
   position: relative;
  border: none;
}
```

Now I want to create the two maps in the page, I have tried but not able to create the maps because I have used the id of name map.

So how to change the id value(map) to class than I will use that class to create the more maps within the
page

Comment: May be this will help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293579/multiple-leaflet-maps-on-same-page-with-same-options

Comment: No, they have created the two id values but  I want to create the more than two maps dynamically

Comment: You want to create dynamic map without any placeholder?

Comment: yes,I want to create the dynamic map

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use the same L.map instance, and make the necessary change on it.
Another way can be to create another DOM with a different ID and use [hide] to show the first or the second map.